# Can unilateral mean unanimous?

Tags: synonyms, context

When deciding among colleagues between two options, everyone present agreed on the same solution. When reporting the result to a member that hadn't taken part, I reported it as "unilateral consensus". I was thinking of *unanimous*.

Merriam Webters's definition of unilateral includes "having parts arranged on one side". Since every member was on the same side, can unilateral still be used in this case? Searching for "unilateral consensus" or "unilateral agreement" I find they mostly refer to cases when only one of many parties benefitted from an agreement.

Comment: How idiomatic is 'unilateral consensus'? Doesn't 'unilateral' when used of agreement / disagreement (and related policies and implementation) mean 'forced through without regard for the other side'? Ie 'ignoring / trampling on the other side', not 'all arranged on one side'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Unilateral” means that one side acts alone; this implies that dissent does exist but is simply powerless to stop it. For instance, if one political party has enough power to pass a law without any votes from the other party(ies), they can act unilaterally.

“Unanimous” means everyone is on the same side; there is no dissent. For instance, a vote to adjourn for lunch is often unanimous because *everyone* is hungry.

Answer (score 5):

No, it can't. *Unilateral* has the specific meaning 'carried out by, or pertaining to, *only* one side'. It assumes that there are two sides in an argument, or several groups/countries involved in a situation.